# En el documento me pone todos los párrafos en formato y tamaño. ¿Cómo asignar formato style y tamaño a parrafos específicos?

Tags: python

En el documento word aparece todos los párrafos en formato y tamaño, solamente quiero que
cambie de formato bold y tamaño en los párrafos que tengan ## o ###.
En el cmd me sale esto:

EJEMPLO MARKDOWN (Titulo)

son ejemplos para ver donde cae.♂♂♂Hola cae aquí ya ves jajaaj xD

4º nivel ejemplo markdown (titulo)

Hola♂♂Es un ejemplo  curioso y bonito además. ♂♂ Hace buen día jajaj.♂♂Saludos.

♀

Los párrafos aparecen en una sola linea en lugar separados además aplica formatos a todos los otros párrafos que no tienen nada que ver.

El script funciona correctamente por otro lado maneja campos especiales llamados citation and bibliography( citas y bibliografias)

```py
import win32com.client
import os

print("Iniciando la aplicación de Word y abriendo el documento...")

# Inicializar la aplicación de Word y abrir el documento
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True

file_path = os.path.abspath("documento_generado.docx")
doc = word_app.Documents.Open(file_path)

# Definir el texto objetivo y el texto de reemplazo
target_text_1 = "###"
replacement_text_1 = ""
target_text_2 = "##"
replacement_text_2 = ""

# Utilizar el objeto Find para buscar en todo el documento
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()

# Buscar todos los párrafos que contienen "###" y guardar su texto
print("Buscando '###' en el documento...")
found_paragraphs_1 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_1
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
    if target_text_1 in paragraph.Range.Text:
        found_paragraphs_1.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Realizar el reemplazo de "###" por " "
if found_paragraphs_1:
    print("Reemplazando '###' por ' '...")
    find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_1
    find_object.Execute(Replace=2)  # 2 = wdReplaceAll
    print(f"Texto reemplazado: {target_text_1} -> {replacement_text_1}")

# Aplicar el formato de negrita a los párrafos donde se ha eliminado "###"
print("Aplicando formato a los párrafos que contenían '###'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_1:
    print(f"Párrafo encontrado: {found_text}")
    for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
        if found_text.replace(target_text_1, replacement_text_1) == paragraph.Range.Text:
            print("Aplicando formato Bold y tamaño de letra 11...")
            paragraph.Range.Bold = True
            paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 11
            print(f"El párrafo ahora tiene formato Bold y tamaño de letra 11. Texto del párrafo: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
            break

# Buscar todos los párrafos que contienen "##" y guardar su texto
print("Buscando '##' en el documento...")
found_paragraphs_2 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_2
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
    if target_text_2 in paragraph.Range.Text:
        found_paragraphs_2.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Realizar el reemplazo de "##" por " "
if found_paragraphs_2:
    print("Reemplazando '##' por ' '...")
    find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_2
    find_object.Execute(Replace=2)  # 2 = wdReplaceAll
    print(f"Texto reemplazado: {target_text_2} -> {replacement_text_2}")

# Aplicar el formato de negrita a los párrafos donde se ha eliminado "##"
print("Aplicando formato a los párrafos que contenían '##'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_2:
    print(f"Párrafo encontrado: {found_text}")
    for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
        if found_text.replace(target_text_2, replacement_text_2) == paragraph.Range.Text:
            print("Aplicando formato Bold y tamaño de letra 16...")
            paragraph.Range.Bold = True
            paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16
            print(f"El párrafo ahora tiene formato Bold y tamaño de letra 16. Texto del párrafo: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
            break

# Imprimir todo el contenido del documento, párrafo por párrafo
print("Imprimiendo el contenido del documento...")
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.Range.Text + '\r\n')

# Guardar y cerrar el documento
print("Guardando y cerrando el documento...")
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
word_app.Quit()

print("¡Hecho!")
```

Gracias, confio que me lo podéis explicar bien. El fallo seguramente que es un fallito tonto.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecutas primero esto con pywin32:

recuerda que debes importar win32com.client

```
# Reemplazar "↵" por "^p" en el documento
print("Reemplazando '↵' por '^p' en el documento...")
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()
find_object.Text = '^l'  # '^l' es el código para '↵'
find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
find_object.Replacement.Text = '^p'  # '^p' es el código para '¶'
find_object.Execute(Replace=2)  # 2 = wdReplaceAll
```

Después ya puedes ejecutar lo siguiente para las almohadillas. Recuerda todo con pywin32 . Es solamente para windows.

```
# Definir el texto objetivo y el texto de reemplazo
target_text_1 = "###"
replacement_text_1 = ""
target_text_2 = "##"
replacement_text_2 = ""

# Utilizar el objeto Find para buscar en todo el documento
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()

# Buscar todos los párrafos que contienen "###" y guardar su texto
print("Buscando '###' en el documento...")
found_paragraphs_1 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_1
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
    if target_text_1 in paragraph.Range.Text:
        found_paragraphs_1.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Realizar el reemplazo de "###" por " "
if found_paragraphs_1:
    print("Reemplazando '###' por ' '...")
    find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_1
    find_object.Execute(Replace=2)  # 2 = wdReplaceAll
    print(f"Texto reemplazado: {target_text_1} -> {replacement_text_1}")

# Aplicar el formato de negrita a los párrafos donde se ha eliminado "###"
print("Aplicando formato a los párrafos que contenían '###'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_1:
    print(f"Párrafo encontrado: {found_text}")
    for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
        if found_text.replace(target_text_1, replacement_text_1) == paragraph.Range.Text:
            print("Aplicando formato Bold y tamaño de letra 11...")
            paragraph.Range.Bold = True
            paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 11
            print(f"El párrafo ahora tiene formato Bold y tamaño de letra 11. Texto del párrafo: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
            break

# Buscar todos los párrafos que contienen "##" y guardar su texto
print("Buscando '##' en el documento...")
found_paragraphs_2 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_2
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
    if target_text_2 in paragraph.Range.Text:
        found_paragraphs_2.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Realizar el reemplazo de "##" por " "
if found_paragraphs_2:
    print("Reemplazando '##' por ' '...")
    find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_2
    find_object.Execute(Replace=2)  # 2 = wdReplaceAll
    print(f"Texto reemplazado: {target_text_2} -> {replacement_text_2}")

# Aplicar el formato de negrita a los párrafos donde se ha eliminado "##"
print("Aplicando formato a los párrafos que contenían '##'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_2:
    print(f"Párrafo encontrado: {found_text}")
    for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
        if found_text.replace(target_text_2, replacement_text_2) == paragraph.Range.Text:
            print("Aplicando formato Bold y tamaño de letra 16...")
            paragraph.Range.Bold = True
            paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16
            print(f"El párrafo ahora tiene formato Bold y tamaño de letra 16. Texto del párrafo: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
            break
```

para iniciar esta app puedes poner esto por ejemplo:

```
import win32com.client
import os

print("Iniciando la aplicación de Word y abriendo el documento...")

# Inicializar la aplicación de Word y abrir el documento
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True
```

Si quieres guardar en pywin32 pones esto:

```
print("Guardando y cerrando el documento...")
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
word_app.Quit()
print("¡Hecho!")
```

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto y lo he publicado para ayudar a la comunidad simplemente.